# Redirect/Subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

What I have currently:

- A wildcard DNS record. So that every subdomain points to `www.galop.gr`
- A dynamically (php) generated .htaccess file where I append the following code for every subdomain I want working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fractalbit.galop.gr$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fractalbit.galop.gr$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.galop.gr/index.php?user=1 [R=301]
```

Everything is working fine, I just want something more if it is possible.

Right now, if someone enters `fractalbit.galop.gr` will be redirected to `http://www.galop.gr/index.php?user=1`

Is it possible to do this **BUT keep *fractalbit.galop.gr* to the address bar of the browser?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R=301] means: do a redirection, and since you're using an absolute address it will also force a redirection, i would just change the rules to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fractalbit.galop.gr$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fractalbit.galop.gr$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?user=1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i needed! A couple more questions if you have the kindness...

1. What is the key part for this? the relative url OR [L]? Or both? Could you briefly explain what [L] means?

2. How should i go, if want to pass GET variables to a subdomain?
For example is http://fractalbit.galop.gr/?v1=test1&v2=test2 correct?

Comment: You're welcome

key part is relative address and removing [ R=301 ], because those things would force a "redirect", without those the server will just rewrite the address internally but will not tell the browser to check on another address 

The [L] statement means that if the request matches this rule it will not try to match any other rule, it will simply stop processing

if you want to pass variables to a subdomain you should specify absolute address starting with http:// but it will force a redirect, to avoid that you may take advantage that both adresses point to the same site